# HTTP redirection target has Content-Disposition header so browsers show the redirecting URL. Does that affect SEO?

Tags: seo, 301-redirect, pdf, download

`www.example.com/fpdfile/` gets a `301` to `www.othersite.example/filepdf/` and there we have attached `Content-Disposition` header.  The user sees only the `www.example.com/fpdfile/` in address bar, but the PDF file is downloaded from `Content-Disposition` attachment value on `www.othersite.example/filepdf/`.

How does google treat that, can this be a reason of low rank of `www.othersite.example` and high rank of `www.example.com`?